# Codeigniter DB or URI problem with unicode

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, unicode, encoding, uri

I'm having a weird problem.

I have this code

$topic contains "海賊_(ONE_PIECE)" from URI /trends/about/海賊_(ONE_PIECE)
I checked to echo $topic and it prints out 海賊_(ONE_PIECE)

```
$sql="SELECT wti.redirect_title FROM wikipedia_timelines AS wti WHERE wti.redirect_title = ? LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql,array($topic));
if ($row = $query->result_array()) 
{
```

The problem is that this code returns $row to be an empty array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [redirect_title] =>  
        )

)
```

However, if I use this code (replacing ? with the actual value of $topic, it works perfectly

```
 $sql="SELECT wti.redirect_title FROM wikipedia_timelines AS wti WHERE wti.redirect_title = '海賊_(ONE_PIECE)' LIMIT 1";
 $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($topic));
 if ($row = $query->result_array()) 
 {
```

Replacing ? with {$topic} will not make it working too.

This problem only occurs when $topic contains ( ) if it doesn't have () it works fine

I wonder what is the problem.
I suppose there is a problem with URI encoding, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: What's the output of `$this->db->last_query()` after it returns the empty array?

Comment: it actually returns correct sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that query binding escapes your input values (im guessing it doesn't like brackets).

try building your sql string with concatenation, like:

```
$sql = "SELECT wti.redirect_title FROM wikipedia_timelines AS wti WHERE wti.redirect_title = '".$topic."' LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

and see if that helps. Or try the active record class, I use it for japanese characters all the time and it seems to work ok.

// EDIT:

To allow brackets in the URI, try and change `application/config.config.php` and set

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()';
```

also try `urldecode($topic);` to get the kanji out.

Comment: it doesn't work on MySQL command line too, but it actually works in mySQL client app (sequelpro) like mysqlmyadmin

Comment: try and change `application/config.config.php` and set `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()';` also try `urldecode($topic);`